# The url "/web" does not match any handlers

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I've been trying to do a simple webapp on appengine, but I got an issue with handlers.
This is my code:

My **app.yaml** file:

```
application: test-app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /web/.*
  script: AppWebInterface.application
```

My **AppWebInterface.py** file:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

When I run the dev_server and visit localhost:8080/web , I get this error:

```
The url "/web" does not match any handlers.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems, one masking the other.

First, `/web/.*` will match `/web/`, `/web/foo`, but not `/web`. There are a few approaches. One is to use

```
- url: /web.*
```

But this will also match `/webelos`. Many that's not a problem for you, because the next step will catch it.

The next problem is that, having passed `/web/foo` through to the application, there's nothing mapping that url pattern to a class. The `WSGIAppliction` is set up to handle `/`, though no such URL will make it to the app given the handler in `app.yaml`.

If you're stuck getting started, try changing the handler in `app.yaml` to `- url: /`. Get something simple working, then add handlers from there.

Comment: Thanks. I just changed the handler to: -url: /web.* and in my AppWebInterface.py I wrote this: application =webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/main', MainPage)], debug=True). But i'm still having a problem now whenever i try to access localhost/web/main, saying that: runtime/wsgi.py", line 269, in _LoadHandler
    raise ImportError('%s has no attribute %s' % (handler, name)) ImportError: <module 'AppWebInterface' from '/home/fethi/Desktop/SocialMon/AppWebInterface.pyc'> has no attribute app. So I changed the "application = webapp2..." by "app = webapp2..." but i'm still having this problem.

Comment: The change you make the WSGIApplication has to work with the handlers in `app.yaml`. Your change routes `/web` to the app, but the app handles `/main`, which isn't routed. Change one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your pattern only match url which contains `/web/` (need to have a '/' after /weg)

modify the pattern and see the result.

```
handlers:
- url: /web.*
  script: AppWebInterface.application
```